Is there any direct method available in roku like JavaScript method .filter and .map
I Have big Array Object. Is there any way to filter data in roku.
Is there any direct method available in roku like JavaScript method .filter and .map.

Sorting
BrightScript includes basic sorting functionality which you can read about in the ifArraySort docs. If you need advanced sorting like nested properties or multi-property sort, you'll need to implement that yourself. But Roku supports sorting an array of objects by a single key like this:
a =  [{id:3, name:"Betty"}, {id:1, name:"Carol"}, {id:2, name:"Anne"} ]

a.SortBy("name") 

'a = [ {id:2, name:"Anne"}, {id:3, name:"Betty"}, {id:1, name:"Carol"} ]

Map
To my knowledge, there is no .map() equivalent in brightscript, so you'll need to implement that yourself using a for loop and a new array. Something like this:
movies = [
    { id: 3, name: "Children of the Corn" },
    { id: 1, name: "A Christmas Carol" },
    { id: 2, name: "Big Buck Bunny" }
]
newArray = []
for each item in movies
  newArray.push(item.id + item.name)
end for

You could make this easier by writing your own map function:
function map(items, callbackFunction)
  newArray = []
  for each item in items
    newItem = callbackFunction(item)
    newArray.push(newItem)
  end for
  return newArray
end function

function init()
    movies = [
        { id: 3, name: "Children of the Corn" },
        { id: 1, name: "A Christmas Carol" },
        { id: 2, name: "Big Buck Bunny" }
    ]
    movies = map(movies, function(x)
        return x.id.ToStr() + x.name
    end function)
end function

NOTE: Function calls in brightscript are much more expensive than in JavaScript, so I wouldn't use this in performance-sensitive situations. this benchmark shows a simple map() fn call is over 50% slower than an inline loop doing the same work:
LoopVsMap -- RESULTS:
__________________________________________________
loop: --- 74,681.00 ops/sec (fastest)
map: ---- 33,432.00 ops/sec (slowest)


how does said benchmark do in JS? i mean, don't use the built-in .map() - what is speed difference between direct work in loop and calling fn in loop?

Here's a benchmark showing javascript performance. (loop: 12m ops/s, handwritten map: 11m ops/sec, native map: 17m ops/sec). https://jsbench.me/8nlyztzryr/2
